# Event handler hit many times rapidly seems to "short-circuit"

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have an event that is raised from a third-party library, which executes on a background thread. This event basically notifies listeners of status updates in the system the library is watching. The handler invokes itself on the UI thread if InvokeRequired is true, and in either case then proceeds to append an entry for the status change to text in a textbox, and pop up a notification in the tray.

Now, the problem is that these status updates can come in very rapidly; the system being monitored can go from its "idle" state through several intermediates to a "ready" state in milliseconds. I need to know that the system has transitioned through all of these intermediate states; however, not all of the state changes are getting to the log. Setting a breakpoint and stepping through the handler shows the oddest behavior; the handler will step through the first couple of lines of code, and will then jump back to the method's entry. It's almost as if either the event or the Windows message pump is aborting the method call because another call to the same method is incoming. Putting the method body in a lock block does not solve it.

I've seen this before in other projects that do not use this third-party library. I wasn't as concerned there, because the rapid-fire event was simply triggering window redraws. If they all happened, great, but if one was short-circuited, there was another in the pipe that would go through. This, however, is a much more application-critical task that must happen every time the event is raised, in order (it doesn't have to happen as fast as the states actually change; definitely not expecting that).

What's the cause of this short-circuiting behavior, and how do I stop it?

Comment: What is the logging mechanism?  Perhaps the log entries for events B and C are failing because a critical resource is locked because it's still logging event A?

Comment: The "log" is very simple; it's appending to the text of a TextBox in a status window, and if it's an event the end user is interested in, pops up a notification. Very simple, but they require being run in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing all of the work synchronously in the thread the event handler fires in it would likely be beneficial to do the work in another thread.

Just wrap everything you're doing in your current event handler in a `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or use `BeginInvoke` to marshal to the UI thread instead of `Invoke`.

I couldn't be sure as I have no knowledge of that library, but it could be that it's unable to fire more events until it finishes executing all of the event handlers for the previous event.

Another option that you may need to do, either to solve this problem, or to prevent your UI from being mad at you for so many updates, is to take the status changes as the come in and just dump them into a collection, and then just periodically check that collection and process all of the changes in a batch.  This would be easier on the event handler for the 3rd party object as it just needs to add an item to a collection, and also easier on the UI as it won't need to update several times in the span of time the monitor can even render the changes.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is most likely new calls to the event handler from the background thread while the call you first started stepping through is still running.

Comment: If that were the case I'd see the cursor jump backwards and forwards, or stay in the same position, as various threads chewed their way through the handler. I'd also see multiple threads inside the handler. Neither of these seem to be the case.

Comment: @KeithS "the handler will step through the first couple of lines of code, and will then jump back to the method's entry" --> this is what it looks like when you re-enter an event handler from the background thread.

Comment: ... But there aren't multiple threads listed in the Threads window as being inside that handler.

Comment: I suspect that's because you're invoking on the main thread. It remains that you're re-entering the event handler because it's called by the background thread.

Comment: OK, so you're saying I need to not be trying to push the event forward to the UI; instead I need to handle the event raised from the background thread quickly, maybe by pushing the relevant information into a queue, and have something else consume that data in its sweet time, kind of like what Servy said.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm saying that the way you're stepping through is going to be confusing because of the threading.